# Execution time of bitwise shift

Tags: c++, bit-shift, execution-time

My question is about bitwise-shifting an integer variable in C++.
Is the execution time of shifting an integer by n (i << n) equal to shifting that integer n times by 1 (i << 1)?

I'm not gonna use a loop for shifting n times. Suppose n = 8. For example I want to compare execution time of the following functions:

```
void f1(int i) {
    i <<= 8;
}

void f2(int i) {
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
    i <<= 1;
}
```

In other word if (i << 8) and (i << 1) take the same time to execute?

Comment: Why don't you test it and find out? Just make sure the compiler doesn't optimize your test cast away.

Comment: Compiler would probably generate same code for both (with some optimization flag).

Comment: Usually there's a shift instruction for the CPU that would do either the 8-bit or the 1-bit shift in one go... but the compiler might use a single 8-bit shift for both your examples anyway.

Comment: This is not worth worrying about. Let the compilers optimizer deal with it and just write the most readable code. And even if the optimizer gets it wrong, something this trivial is highly unlikely to be notizable regardless. Simple readable code is usually also easier for the optimizer to get right.

Comment: Remember if you benchmark make your test large enough (do at least 10s of thousands) so that the execution is at least a few ms.

Comment: barring optimization, `i <<= 8` would require one CPU instruction set while the code in `f2` would require eight CPU instruction sets. By definition, executing one instruction set is faster than eight identical instruction sets.

Comment: Addendum to @Great.And.Powerful.Oz's comment: If you are writing for performance and *not* using compiler optimization, reconsider this choice.

Comment: Leaving optimisation aside - cook eight eggs together within the same pot, afterwards, take eight eggs, and cook each one separately in the pot. Which way takes longer?

Comment: Your question is similar to asking _"Is the execution time of calling a given function one time equal to calling it n times, where n > 1?"_ The answer is obvious.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz It's not obvious to someone who doesn't know the time complexity of the function being called (in this case it's constant). That's important to know because the inputs to the function aren't the same in both cases. This is what Ln x dx is really trying to inquire.

Comment: @JordanMelo: We'll have to agree to disagree. Climbing 100 stairs is faster than climbing 800 stairs.

Comment: If your question is about loop unrolling, then _in general_ that can result in faster, if larger code. But careful consideration must be given to how the loop is unrolled.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz This problem is not equivalent to climbing stairs. He's asking if `i << 8` and `i << 1` take the same time to execute.

Comment: @JordanMelo, no he's asking the execution time of `i << 8` _once_ versus `(i << 1)` _eight times_. Doing any task eight times, whether climbing stairs or executing the same instruction set, is clearly and obviously slower than doing it once.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz How is it obvious that `i << 8` and `i << 1` take the same time to execute? They don't have the same inputs. You're assuming the asker knows that these are equivalent to one instruction and that "obviously" they both execute in the same amount of time. Clearly this is not obvious to the asker.

Comment: Both execute in the same time on modern CPUs but they did not always. I agree I don't think the OP knows that.

Comment: @JordanMelo, that's not the question he asked.

Comment: If he would be interested into loop unrolling effect, he should have posted `f1: size_t n = 8; while (n--) i <<= 1;` vs that `f2` ... that would be still a bad example of loop unrolling study, as the `<<=` is special CPU instruction, but at least it would give hint for answering, what he is trying to assess.

Comment: I think that was exactly the question asked. However we could use some clarification here from the OP.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz It doesn't matter how it's worded. That's essentially what he's asking. The point is that it's not obvious to him that `i << 1` 8 times takes longer than `i << 8` once **because** he is not aware of the fact that `i << 1` and `i << 8` take the same time. Why should that fact be obvious to the asker?

Comment: @JordanMelo In other word I'm asking if i << 8 and i << 1 take the same time to execute. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit:
The `<<=` alias bitwise left shift is on most of the CPUs translated directly into single machine code instruction. On x86 CPU family by historical reasons both shift variants are available, either specialized shift by one, or generic one by immediate #n (or even the fully dynamic one shifting by number in other register `cl`). But for example on ARM CPU, which is RISC-like, there's only shift-by-n, so even `<<=1` is translated into the same instruction, as `<<=8`, only with different parameter (and the execution speed is constant).

---

No. At most of the modern CPU both variants of shift (by 1 or #n) take the same time to execute.

At historic CPUs, when shift-by-#n was available, it may have been a tad slower than shift-by-1 (if the shift-by-1 instruction was available too), but generally much more faster than calling the shift-by-1 #n times.

Hmm, this was just "IIRC", so I went for google ([source](http://zsmith.co/intel_s.html#sal)): the 80386 had already the same timing, but from the details about 80286 it's tricky... it looks like for some `n` it may have been faster to write it as several shifts by one. So.. this question is like ~30y late.